# Regular expression to validate money with minimum value

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am using below regular expression to validate money which works fine.

```
^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$
```

Now I want to add minimum amount also like minimum amount should be `20,000`
Can anyone please help me out.

**Fiddle: https://regexr.com/5h5bf**

**fiddle updated with correct expression**

Comment: Why not check if the value is `>= 20000` in plain code?

Comment: ^ that. Plus, it sounds like you're just using `20,000` as an example (right?). To validate numeric ranges using regex, you'd be using very different patterns for each one. Don't expect a pattern that you can use for _any_ "minimum amount" by switching a couple of digits.

Comment: I have a form with other fields also with other form validations. Validating like above is an option but lost uniformity and I don't want to apply any alternate way

Comment: In my experience, form validators should ship with common things like `min`, or `max`. If your validator library *only* exposes regex for validation, it sounds really bad and hard to use. I'd advise using a different validation library. Even HTML5 exposes number validation for inputs.

Comment: @JvdV pls check fiddle now. I updated correct one now.

Comment: @VLAZ it's not just numbers but formatted (comma separated) numbers, so simple html5 min/max or even simple range validation regular expression won't work

Comment: @JvdV seems to be working. +1

Comment: @JvdV yes, such numbers are not validating too, so need to update regex more

Comment: @JvdV can you modify the expression?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi, I have put an answer down below for you a while back. See if that ticks your boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the comments, I'm not sure if regex would be your way forward, yet you seem determined. It seems that you are looking to validate a comma-seperated string that needs to start at 20,000, where each second part of the number is 3 digits long. I came up with:

```
^(?:[2-9]\d|[1-9]\d\d|[1-9],\d{3})(?:,\d{3})+$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/m11W2g/3)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group.

  - `[2-9]\d` - A digit ranging from 2-9 followed by any digit.
  - `|` - Or.
  - `[1-9]\d\d` - A digit ranging from 1-9 followed by any two digits.
  - `|` - Or.
  - `[1-9],\d{3}` - A digit ranging from 1-9 followed by a comma and any three digits.
  - `)` - Close 1st non-capture group.
- `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group.

  - `,\d{3}` - A comma followed by any three digits.
  - `)+` - Close 2nd non-capture group and repeat at least once.
- `$` - End string ancor.

---

As an alternative you could also use lookaheads, e.g.:

```
^(?=.{6,})(?!1.{5}$)[1-9]\d?\d?(?:,\d{3})+$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/m11W2g/4)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?=.{6,}` - Positive lookahead for at 6 or more characters.
- `(?!1.{5}$)` - Negative lookahead for 1 followed by 5 characters till end string.
- `[1-9]\d?\d?` - A digit ranging from 1-9 followed by two optional digits (you could also write `[1-9]\d{0,2}`).
- `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group.

  - `,\d{3}` - A comma followed by any three digits.
  - `)+` - Close non-capture group and repeat at least once.
- `$` - End string ancor.